# What php/server settings might prevent simplexml_load_file() from working?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using `simplexml_load_file()` to grab the contents of an RSS feed:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file('http://www.iolproperty.co.za/roller/news/feed/entries/rss');
```

This works as expected on my local server but fails silently when deployed to my client's production server, returning an empty result.

The `phpinfo()` function says that SimpleXML support is enabled, and it does seem that I'm allowed to access remote files (cURL functions work just fine). I've also tried loading different RSS feeds. Again, they work locally but return empty when deployed.

Comment: Enable error reporting. That should tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file` need that `allow_url_fopen` directive is enabled in `php.ini` if you want to load an external file. Curl functions does not need this directive, so it works for you.

Comment: To understand why this is so, consider that `simplexml_load_file($url)` is basically the same as `simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url))`, and `file_get_contents($url)` is basically short-hand for using `fopen($url)` and reading out the contents of the "file". The ini setting allows you to treat URLs as "files" for `fopen` _and all related functions_.

Answer (score 1):

A production server might have outgoing internet request blocked to prevent abuse. Another reason could be that its a different PHP version or some mods are not included in the configuration. Use error reporting to see the error message

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

//UPDATE

You could also check if you get a value back from the server like

```
$c = implode('', file('http://www.iolproperty.co.za/roller/news/feed/entries/rss'));
print $c;
$rss = simplexml_load_string($c);
```

and check what the others are saying, check if `allow_url_fopen` option is enabled

Answer (score 1):

You have to set [allow_url_fopen option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled for that to work.